# How can we store CNN weights from keras .h5 file into hyperledger fabric?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to store model weights from training a model in keras library (.h5 file) inside a participant of hyperledger. Since the .h5 file is too large (160 mb) and is in binary format.

In order to convert to UTF-8 encoded character I have used base64. But the file size increased to 200 mb. It seems impossible to copy the whole text to the ledger.

**model.cto file:**

```
participant Cat identified by animalId{
    o String animalId
    o String CNNclassifier   //Here I want to save the weights
}
```

Even copying the whole 200mb file made my pc slow. And I am not even sure if the string variable can store that large content.